# Ruby 'to_json' throws ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, encoding

In rails console, I get:

```
hash = {"name"=>"სსიპ ოთარ ჩხეიძის სახელობის სოფელ ყე\xE1\x83"}
#=> {"name"=>"სსიპ ოთარ ჩხეიძის სახელობის სოფელ ყე\xE1\x83"}
hash.to_json
#>> ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
from /home/edmodo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@one-eye/gems/activesupport-json_encoder-1.1.0/lib/active_support/json/encoding/active_support_encoder.rb:79:in `gsub'
```

`"\xE1\x83".to_json`'s not working may be due to non UTF-8 characters.

Any help is appreciated.

If hash is converted to a string, then it works, but it adds garbage characters like `u003E` with lots of extra backslashes.

```
hash.to_s.to_json
#=> "\"{\\\"name\\\"=\\u003E\\\"სსიპ ოთარ ჩხეიძის სახელობის სოფელ ყე\\\\xE1\\\\x83\\\"}\""
```

Comment: Garbage? U+003E is the `>` character from `"name"=>`

Comment: `\xE1\x83` are the first two bytes of a 3-byte character sequence, so it's only a partial character. The fix is to truncate strings at character boundaries, not in-between.

Answer (score 2):

That is because your input String contains *invalid byte sequence in UTF-8*, as the error message precisely tells.
You can check it like

```
hash['name'].valid_encoding?  # => false
```

Fundamentally, you should fix the input string, removing all the *invalid byte sequence* characters; in your example, it is `"\xE1\x83"`

If for some reason you need to preserve the byte sequence and encode it to a standard JSON, I think you must encode the string first, because JSON does not accept a binary data but valid UTF-8 strings only. Note a string with an *invalid byte sequence* is a binary data, as far as JSON is concerned.

In Rails, you can use Base64 encoding as follows:

```
hash['name'] = Base64.encode64 hash['name']
hash.to_json  # => a valid JSON
```

In decoding, you must specify the encoding, such as,

```
hj = hash.to_json
Base64.decode64(JSON.parse(hj)['name']).force_encoding('UTF-8') # => Decoded string
```

Note the reproduced string is **NOT** a valid UTF-8 in your case anyway.  But it would help to display in Rails console.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not afraid of losing content, may use this solution:

```
pry(main)> 
{"name"=>"სსიპ ოთარ ჩხეიძის სახელობის სოფელ ყე\xE1\x83".force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT").encode('UTF-8', undef: :replace, replace: '')}.to_json

=> "{\"name\":\"     \"}"
```

Comment: If I was in the OP's shoes, I would be happy to get rid of `"\xE1\x83"` in the input string, but perhaps would not want to lose any other parts of it…?

Comment: I found `invalid: :replace` instead of, or in addition to, `undef: :replace` would achieve it. @Alexey, please feel free to update your answer, if you want (which might help future visitors).

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'json'

def cleanup(string)
  text = ''
  string.each_char { |char| text << char if char.valid_encoding? }
  text
end

hash = { "name" => "სსიპ ოთარ ჩხეიძის სახელობის სოფელ ყე\xE1\x83" }
hash.transform_values! { |value| cleanup(value) }

puts hash.to_json

{"name":"სსიპ ოთარ ჩხეიძის სახელობის სოფელ ყე"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Stefan, Masa Sakano and Alexey Strizhak. Your suggestions helped me a lot. 
This is correct that the string has invalid byte sequence characters.
What I did is just to keep valid encoding characters as below -

```
"სსიპ ოთარ ჩხეიძის სახელობის სოფელ ყე\xE1\x83".chars.select(&:valid_encoding?).join
=> "სსიპ ოთარ ჩხეიძის სახელობის სოფელ ყე"
```

This will remove the incomplete/invalid characters like "\xE1\x83".

Again thanks a lot everyone for helping me out to understand the problem and suggesting solutions.

Comment: `"ყე\xE1\x83".encode('UTF-8', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '')` would be more efficient.

Comment: Besides, your solution does not work if the encoding of the original string is `ASCII-8BIT`, in which case any byte is regarded as **valid**.